# Join 2 tables with Sub Query and Union in MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql, left-join, union

I have table 1 and table 2, where Table 1 is master table and Table 2 is child table. Relationship of both table has been implemented by primary key of table 1(id) with table_1_id column in table 2.

I need to fetch data from table 1 by check data in table with below conditions in single query:

If table 1 data does not exist in child table 2

- fetch data from table 1

If table 1 data exist in table 2 and status=0 in table 2,

- fetch data from table 1

If table 1 data exist in table 2 and status=1 in table 2,

- Ignore data from table 1

Below is my SQL, but it always return same number of records and not considering 2nd and 3rd condition:

```
select t1.* from table_1 as t1
where t1.id IN(
SELECT t1.id
            from table_1 as t1
            LEFT JOIN table_2 AS t2 ON t2.table_1_id=t1.id
            UNION ALL
            SELECT table_1_id
            from table_2 as t2 where t2.deleted = "0"'
)
```

I have tried EXIST in where clause instead of t1.id IN in above query but no luck, Can someone guide me what is wrong in this query and how can correct my query to achieve records from table?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think a simple (anti) `JOIN` should do what you need:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM table_1 AS t1
LEFT JOIN table_2 AS t2 ON 
    t1.id = t2.table_1_id
    AND t2.status = 1
WHERE t2.table_1_id IS NULL
```

For each row in `table_1`, we look for a matching row in `table_2` that also has `status` = 1.  The `WHERE` clause ensures we exclude any such rows - ie `table_1` rows are only included if there is no matching row in `table_2` (condition 1), or if the matching row has some `status` that's different to 1 (conditions 2 and 3).

Answer (score 0):

It seems you made the task more complicated than it actually is. You want to select all t1 rows for which not exists a t2 row with status 1.

```
SELECT *
FROM table_1 AS t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
  SELECT NULL
  FROM table_2 AS t2
  WHERE t2.table_1_id = t1.id
  AND t2.status = 1
);
```

The same with `NOT IN`:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_1
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT table_1_id FROM table_2 WHERE status = 1);
```

Be aware that `NOT IN` fails when there are nulls in the looked-up column. So, if table_1_id can be null, then add `AND table_1_id IS NOT NULL` in the subquery.